# How to set up YouTube channel with 'user' format?

Tags: youtube

For example, PewDiePie's channel homepage link is `https://www.youtube.com/user/PewDiePie`, while mine is `https://www.youtube.com/channel/CHANNELID`.

Can I get my channel link into this format: `http://www.youtube.com/user/CHANNELNAME`?

Answer (score 1):

The `/user/` URLs are [legacy URLs](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6180214?hl=en-GB). These can no longer be used if you created channels off late

> Example: youtube.com/user/partnersupport
>
> Depending on when your channel was created, your channel may have a
>   username. Even if your channel name has changed since you chose your
>   username, you can still use this URL to direct to your channel.
>   Unfortunately, existing usernames cannot be changed. Usernames are no
>   longer required and they are not created for channels today.